# Prove that $\sum (-1)^n f_n(x) $ uniformly converges in I

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, functions

I need some clue on the proof of the following question:

Suppose $f_n$ is a series of functions which are defined in I, descending there to 0. Assume that:
$\exists a \in I : f_n(x) \leq f_n(a)$
for every $x \in I$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$

Prove that $\sum (-1)^n f_n(x) $ uniformly converges in I

Thanks :)

Comment: Hint: Use the Alternating Series Test

Comment: @WaveX That alone doesn't suffice here.

Comment: @ Dr. MV Could it be a good starting point?

Comment: $f_n(x)\to 0$ uniformly and monotonically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using basic principles, we see that given $\epsilon >0$ there exists a number $N$ such that whenever $n>N$, $0\le f_n(a)<\epsilon$.

Then, we have for that given $\epsilon>0$ and corresponding $N$

$$\begin{align}
\left|\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^nf_n(x)-\sum_{n=1}^N (-1)^nf_n(x)\right|&=\left|\sum_{n=N+1}^\infty (-1)^nf_n(x)\right|\\\\
&\le f_{N+1}(x)\\\\
&\le f_{N+1}(a)\\\\
&<\epsilon
\end{align}$$

And we are done!

Comment: Can you please explain your steps, why do you subtracts the sums? Is it done by definition?

Comment: @EitanKosman We just showed that the sequence of partial sums converges uniformly to the series.  Help me understand what part of this development is the obstacle.

Comment: I dont understand the following inequallity: $|\sum_{n=N+1}^{\infty} (-1)^n f_n(x)| \leq f_{n+1}(x)$

Comment: See [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test#Formulation).

Comment: Thanks! Could I use Cauchy criterion for uniform convergence too?

Comment: There are several alternative ways forward.  Certainly, I encourage you to test the application of Cauchy's criterion for uniform convergence and see if it works here.